# ¿Es posible diferenciar los selectores solo con $(this)?

Tags: jquery

Tengo este trozo de código:

```js
$('#btn_1, #btn_2').on('click', function() {    

  // Button 1
  let btn1conSpan = $('#btn_1 span');
  
  // Button 2
  let btn2conSpan = $('#btn_2 span');
  
  console.log(btn1conSpan.text());
  console.log(btn2conSpan.text());  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1"><span>Span1</span> Button 1</button>
<button id="btn_2"><span>Span2</span> Button 2</button>
```

Cual funciona correctamente, ahora mi pregunta, es cuando quiero usar el selector `$(this)`:

¿Es posible de alguna manera de saber cual de los `id`'s se ha presionado (**sin usar condiciones** (`if ( .. )`))? ¿De tal forma que muestre el resultado como el primer ejemplo?

El segundo ejemplo muestra la idea que tengo, pero obviamente no da el resultado deseado:

```js
$('#btn_1, #btn_2').on('click', function(){
  
  let $this       = $(this);

  // Button 1
  let btn1conSpan = $this.find('span'); // Que sea el selector #btn_1
  
  // Button 2
  let btn2conSpan = $this.find('span'); // Que sea el selector #btn_2
  
  console.log(btn1conSpan.text()); // Resultado deseado: Span1
  console.log(btn2conSpan.text()); // Resultado deseado: Span2 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1"><span>Span1</span> Button 1</button>
<button id="btn_2"><span>Span2</span> Button 2</button>
```

El resultado deseado del ejemplo 2 sea:

```
Span1
Span2
```

**EDIT**:

Veo que es algo lioso de entender la pregunta.

Simplifico lo máximo posible:

```
$('#btn_1, #btn_2').on('click', function() {    

  // Quiero seleccionar con $(this) de esta forma

  $(this).elemento1; // Que sea #btn_1
  $(this).elemento2; // Que sea #btn_2
});
```

Hay una forma de hacerlo así de simple?

Comment: ¿Por qué no quieres usar una condición para saber cual elemento fue clickeado?

Comment: @Jorius - No es que no quiera, simplemente quiero saber si hay una posibilidad.. si no la hay me quedo con la primera (más limpia)

Comment: ¿Entonces en si cual es tu pregunta o problema? Porque básicamente ya te estás respondiendo, ¿Quieres identificar el `id` del elemento clickeado y mostrar el texto de todo lo anidado en el selector?

Comment: @Jorius - Es resultado deseado es `Span1 Span2` como el primer ejemplo

Comment: ¿Siendo accedido solo por UN scope? en este caso $(this) ?

Comment: @Jorius - Exacto

Comment: Ahora me ha quedado claro, ¡me doy a la tarea de edición que está bueno el problema! :D

Comment: @aldanux y con target, te ayudaria?

Comment: @x-rw - todas las propuestas son bienvenidas, siempre y cuando tenga el resultado deseado y si es posible sin usar condiciones

Comment: La respuesta de @Deivis hace lo que deseas.

Comment: @DarkFenix - Nop...no es lo que busco.. ademas ni muestra la id :/

Comment: No termino de comprender. ¿Entonces lo que quieres es que se lancen los dos? ¿Están los dos encapsulados bajo el mismo ancestro? ¿Existen más elementos o sólo esos dos (p.e. un #btn_3 al que no se le asigna el evento)?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - Correcto... el segundo ejemplo me da el resultado `Span1 Span1` cuando quiero que sea `Span1 Span2` usando this y sin _complicar_ demasiado el código... (que sea similar y simple como el ejemplo 1)

Comment: ¿Y no puedes quieres el selector que ya tienes dentro de la función?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - No entiendo tu último comentario

Comment: `$('#btn_1, #btn_2').on('click', function(){ $("#btn_1, #btn_2").each(function() { console.log($(this).find("span").text()) }); }); `. Me imagino que quieres hacerlo sin usar el texto del selector dentro de la función

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - No..la respuesta de Jorius ya lo ha propuesto... pero pregunto si hay una posibilidad de acceder con this a los dos elementos al mismo tiempo, ejemplo: `$(this).elemento1; $(this).elemento2;`.. me explico? Sin complicar demasiado el código... Si NO es posible me quedo con el primer ejemplo

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro - He editado la pregunta... espero que se entienda ahora mejor...

Comment: En teoría, sólo con `$(this)` no se podría hacer. `this` es el elemento objeto de la acción, pero no guarda ningún tipo de información de los otros elementos que haya en el selector, por lo que desde btn_1 no se podría saber si btn_2 es parte del selector para hacer click en él (y viceversa). Por eso preguntaba que si esa era tu estructura, porque lo más parecido sería seleccionar los elementos hermanos y forzar un click en ellos también

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En teoría, sólo con `$(this)` no se podría hacer. `this` es el elemento objeto de la acción, pero no guarda ningún tipo de información de los otros elementos que haya en el selector, por lo que desde `btn_1` no se podría saber si `btn_2` es parte del selector para hacer click en él (y viceversa).

Por eso preguntaba que si esa era tu estructura, porque lo más parecido sería seleccionar los elementos hermanos y forzar un click en ellos también... aunque eso también es un poco complicado (tampoco en exceso).

En versiones antiguas de jQuery estaba [`selector`](https://api.jquery.com/selector/) que te devolvía el selector utilizado, pero se consideró obsoleto a partir de la versión 1.7 y se eliminó en la 1.9 (aparte de que parece que no era muy eficaz).

Otra opción, aunque personalmente la consideraría hacer algo de trampa, es pasar el selector como parámetro al controlador del evento click y a partir de ahí usarlo para realizar lo que quieres (algo parecido a lo que ponía en los comentarios y al [método de Jorius](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50187/250)). Usando [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) puedes pasar datos opcionalmente:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

que se leerán en el `dataset`. Sí técnicamente no es `this`, por eso digo que es "trampa", pero funciona y sólo tendrías que escribir el selector en un sitio:

```js
var miSelector = '#btn_1, #btn_2';

$(miSelector).on('click', { selector: miSelector }, function(e){
  
  $(e.data.selector).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find("span").text() );
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<button id="btn_1"><span>Span1</span> Button 1</button>
<button id="btn_2"><span>Span2</span> Button 2</button>
```

Comment: lo suponía que no hubiera un método más _limpio_ ... +1

Answer (score 2):

***No creo*** que se puedan diferenciar los *selectores* mediante el *objeto* `$(this)` (no encontré nada en la documentación oficial y buscando un rato por internet) pero puedes asignar cada uno de los *objetos* a una *variable* de la siguiente forma:

Creamos una función llamada `trigger` pasandole como *argumento* nuestro *selector* y que se desencadena cuando cualquiera de nuestros elementos sea *clickeado*, allí en la función le hacemos un `.each` a dichos elementos y pusheamos los respectivos objetos al objeto `buttons` y luego mostramos sus respectivos `text` como ***variables independientes***

```js
var buttons = {};

function trigger(selector){
  $(selector).each(function(i, e){
    let c = i+1;
    buttons['btn'+c+'conSpan'] = $('#' + e.id + ' span');
  });
}

$('#btn_1, #btn_2').on('click', function() {
  trigger('#btn_1, #btn_2');
  console.log(buttons.btn1conSpan.text());
  console.log(buttons.btn2conSpan.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1"><span>Span1</span> Button 1</button>
<button id="btn_2"><span>Span2</span> Button 2</button>
```

Comment: La verdad no me es útil... es lo mismo del ejemplo 2... pero quiero el resultado como el ejemplo 1

Comment: @aldanux He editado mi respuesta, puedes revisar

Comment: @Jorius pero eso es lo que no quiere

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo que es lo que quiere entonces...

Comment: @Jorius en realidad el resultado de tu ejemplo esta perfecto, pero El no quiere usar this

Comment: @x-rw Según lo que redactó en su pregunta, lo que no quiere es usar condicionales

Comment: En principio esta correcto tu código pero se complica en el momento cuando quiero tenerlo por separado las variables... el primer ejemplo hace ya lo que tienes aquí creado con `$.each()` pero yo pregunto por un método como en el segundo ejemplo... se que no es fácil o posible por eso la pregunta si hay una posibilidad

Comment: @x-rw - claro que se puede usar this... lo que no quiero usar son condiciones

Comment: @aldanux Entiendo, quieres poder acceder independientemente a cada objeto mediante el selector? pues yo creo que con el .each que hice es suficiente, no?

Comment: Exactamente... pero el each no hace otra cosa como el ejemplo 1 solo que selecciono los dos id's por separado sin usar this... y la pregunta es si es posible de usar con this pero igual o similar al ejemplo 1.... :)

Comment: @aldanux he vuelto a editar mi respuesta, puedes revisar de nuevo :D

Comment: +1 - no es exactamente lo que busco ya que se _complica_ bastante el código... pero al menos no haz usado ninguna condición ;)

Comment: Y también creo que no sea posible pero esperare un tiempo a ver si da alguien con la tecla...

Comment: @aldanux Marcada como favorita a ver que sucede, ojalá alguien te pueda ayudar en concreto, yo seguiré buscando un poco más a ver que me encuentro

Comment: Donde empleas el selector this ? qué es lo que requiere el OP

Answer (score 1):

Espero sea útil.

```
<ul id="equipos">
     <li id="1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
     <li id="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
     <li id="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
     <li id="4"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul> 

$('#equipos').click(function(e){
     var id = e.target.id;
     alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero sea lo que buscas.

```js
$('#btn_1, #btn_2').on('click', function(e) {    
  let val = $(this).find('span').text();
  let id = $(this).attr('id');
     console.log(val);
     console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn_1"><span>Span1</span> Button 1</button>
<button id="btn_2"><span>Span2</span> Button 2</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

Comment: Lo siento pero tampoco es eso, porque quiero al mismo tiempo los dos elementos...

Comment: Su pregunta es encontrar el id del elemento que se presiono. this hace referencia al elemento que se presionó. y no es posible referenciar al que no se presionó con este selector. por lo tanto  no entiendo el contexto de la pregunta.

Comment: He editado la pregunta... espero que se entienda ahora mejor...

Comment: La respuesta es No. dentro el click , this hace referencia al elemento que se dió click. a nada más.

Answer (score 1):

En complemento a la [respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50210/16597), el código se podría simplificar más y con el beneficio de utilizar [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Así por ejemplo:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#btn_1, #btn_2', function(evt){
  $(evt.handleObj.selector).each(function() {
    console.log($(this).find('span').text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn_1"><span>Span1</span> Button 1</button>
<button id="btn_2"><span>Span2</span> Button 2</button>
```